# Is it possible to make Nanosize GPS tracker?

Tags: nanotechnology, navigation

Is it possible to make gps tracker in 2cm hair sized?

Literature says there are also large restrctions... so I want to know what is the restriction.
experts say that if gps tracker get more smaller it definitely make quantum size effect... So it is impossible
What minimum antenna length would be enough to receive and send the signal in case of nano sized  GPS tracker? Can it be be 0.05mmx0.05mmx20mm

3. if we want to run the GPS tracker, it need at least 50mW,  there is alot of thermo tech for harventing energy from body temperature, eventhough its power is very little micron watt.. -->
   gps chip could be downsized... nano transistor and diode and circiut and wafers... --> but if is too small... heat sink and circuit resist would be stronger and chip would be burn...

   last dilema is for power energy harvesting from body is only micron Watt

   I want to know the weigt of that tracker. --. it is surely more heavy comparing to real hair -->it is surely more heavy or almost same comparing with 2cm copper wire --> maybe it is more heavy than what I mention.. Because it has a lot of materials and chips and circuit in hair sized.... --> pls. explain me is it heavy compare to same sized copper wire?

Comment: Don't we already do this?

Comment: I'm fairly sure that we already have the capacities today. We would be able to build smaller tracker. They're just going to get more and more expensive the smaller you go

Answer (score 2):

*Hollywood is lying to you.* GPS is a receive-only device like your car's FM radio.

To track someone with GPS you need to send the coordinates from device to the guy tracking it somehow. That requires sending a signal to a receiver in range. Which can then forward it to the guy tracking it.

"GPS trackers" in use today (to tracking a delivery truck fleet for example) use the cell phone network to text the location of the truck to the server.